How to Customize Header and Footer with Elementor in a Theme Without Site Editor Support
Problem:
I'm using a custom theme that doesn't support the Wordpress Site Editor. I want to create a new splash page with a modified header and footer that hides the nav menu. Elementor is enabled.
Question:
How can I use Elementor to edit the existing header and footer templates from my theme and conditionally hide the nav menu for the splash page?
Additional Details:

Theme: custom_theme
Elementor Version: 3.23.4
WordPress Version: 6.5.5


You can use CSS just add an ID or class on the nav menu and find the page id of your splash page on the inspect element is always on the body class.
.page-id-6 .nav-menu-to-hide {
  display:none;
}

